# Create a list with one named column in R

Tags: r

Okay, I'm stupid, but:

How can I create a list with one column, 10 rows and a column name, and the same numeric value in all fields? I know how to append it, e.g.

```
mylist["column_name"] <- rep(1, nrow(mylist))
```

but not how to create it on its own.

It should look like this:

```
> mylist
   column_name
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want a list and not a data frame (as that is what your example looks like)? You can get it like this:

```
data.frame(column_name=rep(1,10))
```

Comment: What I copypasted above was a list extracted from an Excel Workbook with XLConnect (at least `typeof(mylist)` said so). But it does not matter, your code works fine for me, because I'm combining this list with a few other lists into a data.frame anyway. So, thank you for your answer, I'm accepting it.